# How to convert pandas DataFrame to a Fasta file?

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, biopython

Hi I have pandas dataframe in which each row is a sequence, how could i convert it to a fasta file ?

For Example if i have the following dataframe :

```
  c1  c2  c3 c4 c5
0  D  C   Y  C  T
1  D  C   E  C  Q
```

The expected output is :

```
>0    
DCYCT
>1
DCECQ
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple version with `print` (you might want to write the lines to a file):

```
for k, v in df.agg(''.join, axis=1).items():
    print(f'>{k}\n{v}')
```

Output:

```
>0
DCYCT
>1
DCECQ
```

Writing as a file:

```
with open('out.fasta', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in df.agg(''.join, axis=1).items():
        f.write(f'>{k}\n{v}\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple columns into one column

```
df2 = df.assign(c = df.c1.astype(str) + df.c2.astype(str) +

      df.c3.astype(str) + df.c4.astype(str) + df.c5.astype(str))
```

The index will be 0 and 1 while the new column "c" will contain the combination of all the columns.